# Windows Store - Pixels Array

Tags: c#, bitmap, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I am working at an app where I need to get the array of pixels from an Image and to edit the Image using the pixels array.

I am using the next code for getting the pixels array from the StorageFile object which indicates the image:

```
public static async Task<byte[]> GetPixelsArrayFromStorageFileAsync(
    IRandomAccessStreamReference file)
{
    using (IRandomAccessStream stream = await file.OpenReadAsync())
    {
        using (var reader = new DataReader(stream.GetInputStreamAt(0)))
        {
            await reader.LoadAsync((uint)stream.Size);
            var pixelByte = new byte[stream.Size];
            reader.ReadBytes(pixelByte);
            return pixelByte;
        }
    }
 }
```

Now, my questions are:

> 1. Why if I load a image which is 6000 x 4000 pixels I have an array of just 8,941,799 which is actually the size of my image on disk?
> 2. How can I access the RGBA channels of the pixels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file has a compressed version of the bitmap, so you need to decode it first. I'd suggest loading it into a `WriteableBitmap` since you need to display it anyway and then access the `PixelBuffer` property of the bitmap to get the actual pixels. You could do something like this:

```
var writeableBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(1, 1);
await writeableBitmap.SetSourceAsync(yourFileStream);
var pixelStream = writeableBitmap.PixelBuffer.AsStream();
var bytes = new byte[pixelStream.Length];
pixelStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
pixelStream.Read(bytes, 0, Bytes.Length);

// Update the bytes here. I think they follow the BGRA pixel format.

pixelStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
pixelStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
writeableBitmap.Invalidate();
```

You can check the extension methods [here](https://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#WinRTXamlToolkit/WinRTXamlToolkit.Shared/Imaging/IBufferExtensions.cs) and [here](https://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#WinRTXamlToolkit/WinRTXamlToolkit.Shared/Imaging/ColorExtensions.cs) to see how to work with the pixels.

Comment: I hoped that I would need to store just the pixel array and to convert it to a BitmapImage when I need to display it. As far as I know, you can not display a WritableBitmap without converting it to a ImageBitmap so what I as doing was converting the pixelArray to an ImageBitmap when I needed to display the image. Is that a good idea?

Comment: No, you can display a `WriteableBitmap` the same way you do `BitmapImage`. They both derive from `BitmapSource` and `ImageSource` which is what an `Image.Source` property accepts as well as `ImageBrush.Source`.

Comment: Another option might be to use [`await BitmapDecoder.GetPixelDataAsync()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br226192.aspx) to get just the pixels and then create a new `WriteableBitmap` IF you want to display it. You'll need to copy the pixels from the array to the `WriteableBitmap` then though.

Comment: You're right, I can set the WritableBitmap as a source for the image. So now I have to store a WritableBitmap, the pixel stream and the pixel array? Or can I just store the WritableBitmap and the pixel array, accessing the stream just when I need to update the WritableBitmap? Or will it take to much time to access the stream every time?

Comment: Or should I just keep the pixel array and reconstruct the WritableBitmap?

Comment: Good questions. You should check all the options and see which one works best, then report the result here. I typically just store the bitmap and only get the stream read, process and write the pixel bytes when I do some processing, but I haven't done it on large images. If you're doing heavy processing on large photos - it might turn out you will need to use DirectX anyway. That was the case in most of my WinRT projects so far! :)